# Vs code не видит скачанные библиотеки в python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

писал раньше код в pycharm , он сразу видел какие библиотеки установлены и сразу помогал дописывать атрибуты и т.д. а vs code не видит скачанные библиотеки как это исправить?

Comment: VS Code "видит" библиотеки, которые находятся в одном с ним виртуальном окружении. Как настроить виртуальное окружение для VS Code можно поискать в интернете.

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас не указан путь к python или он неверен.  Если пользуетесь дополнением "Python" то в строке состояния внизу должен быть указан текущий интерпритатор, нажмите на этот текст и укажите актуальный путь. Второй вариант в настройках задать переменную python.pythonPath. Например:  `"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python\\python.exe"`

Comment: Ребят, кто-нибудь нашел ответ на этот вопрос? Я только начинаю писать код, и мне очень помогало автозаполнение, пока в один момент не пропало. Искал где только мог, но нигде ответа не нашелю

Answer (score 2):

Первое и важное необходимо установить [расширение для python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). Данное расширение поддерживает заполнение для кода и функцию `IntelliSense`. `IntelliSense` - это общий термин для ряда функций, которые и дают подсказки в коде для всех ваших файлов как `built-in`, так и для сторонних модулей. `IntelliSense` отображает переменные, методы, объекты классов и документацию в момент ввода. Более подробную информацию можно подчерпнуть на [официальной страничке](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_autocomplete-and-intellisense) посвещенной данному вопросу.

Поскольку всегда, а правильнее сказать, как правило используются виртуальные пространства, то и модули для будут отличаться от глобальных установок. В этом случае в `VSCode` предусмотрено переключение на тот интерпретатор, который необходим в данном рабочем процессе.

Приведу пример. При помощи `python -m venv env` команды я создам виртуальное пространство для проекта, которое будет включать нужную версию python и модули, которые нужны **только** для данного проекта. Если не конфигурировался проект изначально при запуске `VSCode` будет цеплять глобальный `python` и глобальные модули (возможно, в новых версиях это не так). Это можно увидеть в нижнем левом углу интерфейса `VSCode`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на данную область появится меню вверху окна с возможностью выбора пространства

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я и могу выбрать нужный мне `python 3.8.6 64-bit ('env':venv)`. Из данного примера можно увидеть, что я могу использовать разные версии `python` и соответственно модули, для которых и будет работать `IntelliSense`.

Answer (score -1):

Мне помогло следующее:

- Нажать ctrl + ,
- В строке ввести venv
- В поле Python: Venv Path ввести путь до виртуального шаблона (для примера у себя я прописал ~/venv)