# Как сделать чтобы VS Code видела модули установленные на удалённой виртуальной машине?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh

Развернул docker с Airflow внутри venv на виртуальной машине Google Cloud Platform.
Подключился ко всему этому делу по SSH из VS Code.

Проблема заключается в том что VS Code не видит модули которые подняты на удалённой виртуальной машине внутри venv.

[image: скрин нерабочего импорта]

Код при этом работает, как можно пофиксить эту проблему?

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1369718/209304), вторую часть ответа, как переключиться на нужный интерпритатор

Comment: Заработало....

Когда я пытался найти ответ на свой вопрос я слишком усложнял запрос лишними терминами, не думал что это так просто

Comment: Можете оценить тот ответ=)